# Android : How to directly go to the download page of an app in play store

Tags: android, google-play

I know its possible from the web URL to directly go to the download page of the app by using this URL :

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>&rdid=<package_name>
```

I wanted to know if there is a similar trick for the mobile version of the Play Store? So when I click the 'Download App' button from my app it directly goes to the 'Accept & Download' page for the target app.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, launch an intent with the action set to action view and using the market scheme for the URI:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")));
```